# Create new Django model int field from existing bool fields

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with several bool fields. I'd like to replace them with a single int field where each bit represents one of the old bools. I've added the new int field and run `makemigrations`. Is there a way I can modify the migrations file and define how I'd like the new int fields' values to be defined? Like I said, I would like them to take the values of the previous bool fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) is what you need.

1. Add new field to the model, apply `makemigrations`.
2. Create a data migration, which would transfer data from old fields to the new one and run it.
3. Remove old fields.

Data migration could be created with:

```sh
python manage.py makemigrations --empty yourappname
```

And inside it you should use [`RunPython`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/migration-operations/#runpython) or [`RunSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) depending on what exactly do you need.